# In a clan war how is the recomended target determined?

Tags: clash-of-clans

In a clan war, how is your "recommended target" determined? Also is there any significance to the numbers?

I was in a clan with no particular rules for the war and got kicked out because I only got 1 star when I attacked. But it was a difficult target (higher town hall) than my recommended . So I guess it sometimes is better to play it safe and attack the easier targets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that is based in your troop level and heroes but Supercell only says:

> During battle day, you will always have a recommended target visible on the war map. The recommended target shows you the closest match for your attack strength based on the defense strength of your opponents. Base layout isn’t taken into consideration, though, nor is your favorite attacking style, so it is a good idea to also check a few bases above it and a few bases below it to see if you can find a target you like better.

Comment: And also it keeps changing. If your original recommended target is one starred by some one else, the it will calculate a new one for you.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended target is based off of your attack strength and their defence strength. Your attack strength is calculated via your toop, hero, and spell levels, and their defence strength is calculated from their defence and trap levels, but their town hall and base layout is not taken into consideration. The recommended targets is the opponent whose defence strength is the closest to your attack strength. The recommended target can change with time when the previous recommended target is starred by another of your clanmate.

Comment: "Your attack strength is calculated via your toop, hero, and spell levels" do you mean what I actually currently have or what I can make? For example a level 7 laboratory could be empty.

Comment: Yeah what you currently have upgraded, not what can be upgraded